# How to secure custom Rest API that is used by a Wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, authentication, plugins

I would like to program a Rest API to be used by a wordpress plugin. The Rest API should only work if the wordpress user also has certain rights. I would like to know how I can protect the Rest API so that it is not used without permission and only works when a Wordpress user is logged in with permission. What is the best way to implement this conceptually? Do you have any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are Wordpress plugin capabilities from an authentication perspective but usually REST APIs do respect HTTP standards so the same [authentication schemes](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwifhbvj7aDxAhVM_7sIHcr-A4MQFjAAegQIBBAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FHTTP%2FAuthentication&usg=AOvVaw2xEdmmFauJnct8211_O_ju) (Basic, OAuth, ApiKey, etc...). It also depends on where would the REST API run such as remote server...

Comment: The Rest API will run on another server. I don't want to implement a second authenticaion. I don't want to have user data on two databases. The authenticaiton and authorization should be on the wordpress site.